# Why Date class object prints the date/time/.. Where as if we print anyother object it gives address?

Tags: java, class, date, object

Consider the Following code snippet:

```
    //Assume the import statements


     Date ob=new Date();
    System.out.println(ob);

    //Where As

    DateFormat df=DateFormat.getDateInstance();//Just as an Example
    System.out.println(df);
```

Output is as follows:

1.Thu Jun 15 14:53:03 IST 2017

2.java.text.SimpleDateFormat@ce9bf0a5( i know this is  hashcode)

Question is : Why the peculiarity with Date ob?

Comment: Because `Date` overrides `Object#toString` and `DateFormat` does not. Also, that is not an address - it's a hashcode.

Comment: By the way, avoid the Date and DateFormat classes. Now supplanted by the java.time classes, whose `toString` implementations happen to generate strings in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to print an object, it calls `toString()` method of the corresponding class. If a class doesn't override `toString()`, it calls the `Object` class version of `toString()`. Now, let's have a look at the javadoc of `Date` class and `toString()` [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString()):

> Converts this Date object to a String of the form:
>
> dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy

So, it overrides `toString()` and hence, we see the String output.

Now, `DateFormat` class (javadoc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html)) lists `toString()` as one of the methods inherited from class `java.lang.Object` (meaning it doesn't override `toSting()`) and hence, `Object` class version of `toString()` is called, resulting in hash of the object getting printed.

[Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) the documentation of `toString()` method of `Object` class, this is what it says:

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of
> the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign
> character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash
> code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal
> to the value of:
>
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())

Answer (score 0):

When we print the object then its `toString()` method is called.

`public String toString()` method is present in `java.lang.Object` class and as Object class is super class of all other classes, so it is available to all classes.

`java.util.Date` class has overridden `toString()` method, that's why.

[Read more](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString())

Answer (score 0):

This is because the Date class overrides the method `toString()` which is declated in `java.lang.Object`, allowing the Date to return a more readable representation.

In `java.lang.Object` the `toString()` is declared as:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

Which is what DateFormat is using